# presentModalViewController

Tags: ipad, presentmodalviewcontroller

I am using the presentModalViewController over a splitview.
My problem is now, that my view on the splitview is for Landscape view but my view changes always to the other view.
Can I check the current Ipad view?

I used this for the presentModalViewController:

```
MyTest *test = [[MyTest alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyTestNib" bundle:nil];//[[MyTest alloc]init];
   [test setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal];
   //  [test setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];
   // [test setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl];
    [self presentModalViewController:test animated:YES];
```

Thank u

Comment: The description of your problem is very confuse. You should try to make it a little clear.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use presentModalViewController, this is deprecated in iOS6.0